# How to draw a line plot with Gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

My file reads:

```
user_number     diff    id  
1                3      1  
1                4      1  
2                7      1  
359              8      1  
857              9      1
```

Here are the command I used and the resulting error:

```
gnuplot> plot "avg_max_min.csv" using 1:2 with boxes  

                                           ^
Error:      warning: Skipping data file with no valid points  
                                                    ^
             x range is invalid
```

Any idea about where the error comes from?

Comment: I tested it, it works for me.

Comment: Is this the whole data file or just a snapshot? My bet is that you either have a problem with missing data (not specified in your file) or a non-constant field separator (though I doubt it can happen if your `csv` file was generated from an external app). In any case, check the `set datafile separator` and `set datafile missing` commands.

Answer (score 4):

To let it works you should change you data file to be

```
    #user_number     diff    id  
    1                3      1  
    1                4      1  
    2                7      1  
    359              8      1  
    857              9      1
```

Gnuplot will treat lines begin with # as comments and will not use at to plot.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in one of the comments, what you propose works without problems in the latest versions of Gnuplot.

There's also the possibility of telling Gnuplot to start to process the file at the second line, skipping the first:

```
plot 'avg_max_min.csv' every ::2 using 1:2 with boxes
```